# How to print a LibreOffice Base Relation Design?

Tags: printing, libreoffice-base

I've gone to the trouble of creating a graphic representation of my database design using Relation Design tool in LibreOffice Base.  How can I print that out/export it to a PDF to share with others, other than with one (or many) screenshot?

Ctrl+P doesn't do anything and there's no Print option in any of the menus that I've seen.

```
LibreOffice 3.5.7.2 
Build ID: 350m1(Build:2)
```